# show numeric inputs in random order in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to randomize the order of numeric inputs in a shiny app. Meaning, if I start with this working example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("inpA", "input A:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
  numericInput("inpB", "input B:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
  numericInput("inpC", "input C:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
  numericInput("inpD", "input D:", 10, min = 1, max = 100)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would like that each time I run the app, the inputs appear in different order on the screen:

[input A: ]

[input B: ]

[input D: ]

[input C: ]

or

[input B: ]

[input A: ]

[input C: ]

[input D: ]

etc.

Thanks

G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To randomize your `numericInput` order in shiny, create dynamic `uiOutput` in server code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("dynInputs")
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
    inpNames <- paste(LETTERS[1:4])

    output$dynInputs <- renderUI({
        div(
            lapply(sample(inpNames), function(x) { 
                numericInput( assign(paste0("inp", x), paste0("inp",x)),
                              label=paste("input",x), value=10, min=1, max=100)
            })

        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]